# How to insert data into a relation table correctly in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have some data in a general table called `ImportH`. The data has been imposted from a csv file. I have also created two tables, `Media` and `Host` (each one has it's respective ID. These tables are related by a third table called `HostMedia`.

Each `Host` can have (or not) different types of `Media` (facebook, email, phone...).

I'll provide some images of the tables:

**Table ImportH**

[image]

**Table Host**

[image]

**Table Media**

[image]

How can I insert the data from the other tables into table `HostMedia`? This table looks like this:

```
create table HostMedia (

    host_id int references Host (host_id),
    id_media int references Media (id_verification),
    primary key (host_id, id_media)
);
```

I have tried this:

```
insert into HostMedia (host_id, id_media)
select Host.host_id, Media.id_verification
from Host, Media;
```

But this does the cartesian product for all the hosts assigning them all the rows on the `Media` table. What's the correct way?

Comment: post example of data as text

Answer (score 0):

The "media" column in your "ImportH" table looks almost like a valid JSON, so this might work:

```
INSERT INTO HostMedia (host_id, id_media)
SELECT i.host_id, m.id_verification
FROM (
  SELECT host_id,
  json_array_elements_text(replace(media,'''','"')::json) AS media_name
  FROM ImportH
) AS i
JOIN Media AS m ON m.media = i.media_name;
```

Notes: it would be easier if you

1. provided text data instead of screenshots
2. used logical column names